# Space in directory name crashing .sh - use "usebackq"?

Tags: bash, unix, directory, space, git-bash

```
dir1='/d/Dropbox/PhD/Experimental Design/APS/Processed_and_Graphed/InvariantQ'
echo $dir1

for f in A*.xlsx
do
   str2=${f%?????}
   if [[ ! -d $dir1/$str2 ]]; then
      mkdir $dir1/$str2
   else
      echo "Directory" $dir1/$str2 "already exists, directory not created"
   fi
   if [[ ! -f $dir1/$str2/$f ]]; then
      mv -v $f $dir1/$str2
   else
      echo "File" $dir1/$str2/$f "already exists, file not copied"
   fi
done
```

I'm trying to get the following script to run, however when it attempts to mkdir $dir1/$str2, it creates:

**/d/Dropbox/PhD/Experimental**

and returns back the error:

**create directory '/d/Dropbox/PhD/Experimental': file exists**

**create directory 'Design/APS/Processed_and_Graphed/InvariantQ': no such file or directory**

I've tried coding the directory name with double quotations, or a '\' in front of the space in 'Experimental Design', but neither method seems to work...  It seems this can be achieved in batch files using "usebackq" -is there a way to do this in GitBash for windows?  If so, where in my code would it be applied?

Also, is anyone aware as to why testing a statement here using "[[" works, whereas a single "[" doesn't?

Comment: See [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your variables to prevent word splitting on the expansion.

```
dir1='/d/Dropbox/PhD/Experimental Design/APS/Processed_and_Graphed/InvariantQ'
echo "$dir1"

for f in A*.xlsx
do
   str2=${f%?????}
   if [[ ! -d $dir1/$str2 ]]; then
      mkdir "$dir1/$str2"
   else
      echo "Directory $dir1/$str2 already exists, directory not created"
   fi
   if [[ ! -f $dir1/$str2/$f ]]; then
      mv -v "$f" "$dir1/$str2"
   else
      echo "File $dir1/$str2/$f already exists, file not copied"
   fi
done
```

It works with `[[` because this is shell syntax, not an ordinary command. It recognizes variables specially and doesn't do work splitting on them. This is the same reason that it allows you to use operators like `<` without quoting them.